# While loop not executing properly with jquery nth-child

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop

I try to get the `background-color` of the `td` using `while loop`. But the code won't execute.

I need to loop until getting the "white" colour as background colour.

This is I have tried:

```
while ($(row1).children('td:nth-child(' + startIndex + ')').css('background-color') == 'rgba(0,0,0,0)') {

    startIndex = startIndex + 1;
}

while ($(row1).children('td:nth-child(' + endIndex + ')').css('background-color') == 'rgba(0,0,0,0)') {

    endIndex = endIndex - 1;
}
```

HTML code:

```
 <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th id="profilepic" data-tag="Image" style="text-align:center;min-width:50px">Image</th>
                        <th id="empName" data-tag="Employee" style="text-align:center;min-width:50px">Employee</th>
                        <th id="0000">00:00</th>
                        <th id="0030">00:30</th>
                        <th id="0100">01:00</th>
                        <th id="0130">01:30</th>
                        <th id="0200">02:00</th>
                        <th id="0230">02:30</th>
                        <th id="0300">03:00</th>
                        <th id="0330">03:30</th>
                        <th id="0400">04:00</th>
                        <th id="0430">04:30</th>
                        <th id="0500">05:00</th>
                        <th id="0530">05:30</th>
                        <th id="0600">06:00</th>
                        <th id="0630">06:30</th>
                        <th id="0700">07:00</th>
                        <th id="0730">07:30</th>
                        <th id="0800">08:00</th>
                        <th id="0830">08:30</th>
                        <th id="0900">09:00</th>
                        <th id="0930">09:30</th>
                        <th id="1000">10:00</th>
                        <th id="1030">10:30</th>
                        <th id="1100">11:00</th>
                        <th id="1130">11:30</th>
                        <th id="1200">12:00</th>
                        <th id="1230">12:30</th>
                        <th id="1300">13:00</th>
                        <th id="1330">13:30</th>
                        <th id="1400">14:00</th>
                        <th id="1430">14:30</th>
                        <th id="1500">15:00</th>
                        <th id="1530">15:30</th>
                        <th id="1600">16:00</th>
                        <th id="1630">16:30</th>
                        <th id="1700">17:00</th>
                        <th id="1730">17:30</th>
                        <th id="1800">18:00</th>
                        <th id="1830">18:30</th>
                        <th id="1900">19:00</th>
                        <th id="1930">19:30</th>
                        <th id="2000">20:00</th>
                        <th id="2030">20:30</th>
                        <th id="2100">21:00</th>
                        <th id="2130">21:30</th>
                        <th id="2200">22:00</th>
                        <th id="2230">22:30</th>
                        <th id="2300">23:00</th>
                        <th id="2330">23:30</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="body1"></tbody>
//Here Iam appending the Row using Jquery
            </table>
```

Comment: Is `row1` a variable or class/id?

Comment: row1 is the currently appending row using jquery

Comment: If `$(row1)` is a `tr`, are you sure it has `tr` elements as children ?

Comment: Please ADD FULL HTML + JQUERY CODE. Current code is very less to understand your problem

Comment: Titus,You are right.It's a row which I'm currently appending to the table.Full Html code is a bit lengthy and irrelevant too..

Comment: Can't you got my point @AlivetoDie ? row1 is an appending row which has td's in it.

Comment: please share the HTML.

Comment: Yes @LibinCJacob ,You can check now!